# Alternate newline character? python

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to represent '\n' with only one character. I am writing a program that uses dictionaries to 'encrypt' text. Because each character is represented in the dictionary, i am having a problem when my program gets to a '\n' in a string, but reads it as '\' 'n' . Is there alternate way to represent a newline, that is only one character? 
This is my code below, sorry if some of the indentation is messed up. I dont entirely understand how to input code into this window. :)

```
##################################
#This program will take an input and encrypt it or decrypt it
#A cipher is used to transform the text, which can either be
#input or from a text file.
#The cipher can be any letter a-z, as well as most commonly used special characters
#numbers and spaces are not allowed.
#For the text, a-z, most special characters, space, and new line may be used.
#no numbers can be encrypted.
##################################

#These three dictionaries are used during the encryption process.
keyDict={'a': 17,'b': 3,'c':16,'d':26,'e':6,'f':19,'g':10,'h':12,
         'i':22,'j':8,'k': 11,'l':2,'m':18,'n':9,'o':23,'p':7,
         'q':5,'r': 20,'s': 1,'t': 24,'u':13,'v':25,'w':21,'x':15,
         'y':4,'z': 14, ' ':42, '.':0,'!': 27, '@': 34, '#': 35, '%': 37,
         '$': 36, "'": 33,'&': 39, '*': 40, ',': 29, '.': 30, '~': 41, ';': 31,
         ':': 32, '?': 28, '^': 38}

refDict2={' ': 43,  'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'g': 7, 'f': 6, 'i': 9,
         'h': 8, 'k': 11, 'j': 10, 'm': 13, 'l': 12, 'o': 15, 'n': 14, 'q': 17,'\n': 42,
         'p': 16, 's': 19, 'r': 18, 'u': 21, 't': 20, 'w': 23, 'v': 22, 'y': 25,
         'x': 24, 'z': 26, ' ':0, '!': 27, '@': 34, '#': 35, '%': 37, '$': 36, "'": 33,
          '&': 39, '*': 40, ',': 29, '.': 30, '~': 41, ';': 31, ':': 32, '?': 28, '^': 38}

refDict={0: ' ', 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h', 9: 'i',
         10: 'j', 11: 'k', 12: 'l', 13: 'm', 14: 'n', 15: 'o', 16: 'p', 17: 'q', 42:'\n',
         18: 'r', 19: 's', 20: 't', 21: 'u', 22: 'v', 23: 'w', 24: 'x', 25: 'y', 26: 'z', 43:' ',
         32: ':', 33: "'", 34: '@', 35: '#', 36: '$', 37: '%', 38: '^', 39: '&', 40: '*',
         41: '~', 27: '!', 28: '?', 29: ',', 30: '.', 31: ';'}


#switch1 reverses a list. It is its own inverse, so we don't need an unswitch function. 
def switch1(l):
    return l[::-1]



#switch2 takes a list as input and moves every fourth entry to the front
#so switch2([a,b,c,d,e,f,g]) returns ([a,e,b,c,d,f,g])
#unswitch2 undoes this, so unswitch2([a,e,c,d,f,g]) returns [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]

def switch2(l):
    List4 = []
    ListNot4 = []
    for i in range(0,len(l)):
        if i%4 == 0:
            List4.append(l[i])
        else:
            ListNot4.append(l[i])
    return List4+ListNot4

def unswitch2(l):
    num4 = len(l)/4 + 1
    fixedList = l[num4:]
    for i in range (0,num4):
        fixedList.insert(4*i,l[i])
    return fixedList



#switch3 takes a list as input and returns a list with the first half moved to the end.
#so switch3([a,b,c,d,e,f]) returns [d,e,f,a,b,c]
#for lists of odd length, switch3 puts the separation closer to the beginning of the list, so the
#middle entry becomes the first entry.
#For example, switch3([a,b,c,d,e,f,g]) returns [d,e,f,g,a,b,c]

def switch3(l):
    return l[len(l)/2:] + l[:len(l)/2]

def unswitch3(l):
    if len(l)%2==0:
        return switch3(l)
    else:
        return l[len(l)/2+1:] + l[:len(l)/2+1]




##################################
#This is the Crypt function.
##################################
def Crypt(text, cipher):
    counter=0
    text=text.lower()
    cipher=cipher.lower()
    keyValue=[]
    textValue=[]
    newValue=[]
    newString=''
    for letter in cipher:
        keyValue.append(keyDict[letter])

    for letter in text:
        textValue.append(refDict2[letter])

    for num in textValue:
        newValue.append(num+keyValue[counter%len(keyValue)])
        counter+=1

    newValue = switch1(newValue)
    newValue = switch2(newValue)
    newValue = switch3(newValue)

    for num in newValue:
        newString+=refDict[num%43]

    return newString

##################################
#This is the Decrypt function
##################################
def Decrypt(encryptedText, cipher):
    counter=0
    cipher=cipher.lower()
    keyValue=[]
    textValue=[]
    finalValue=[]
    finalString=''

    for letter in encryptedText:
        textValue.append(refDict2[letter])

    textValue = unswitch3(textValue)
    textValue = unswitch2(textValue)
    textValue = switch1(textValue)

    for letter in cipher:
        keyValue.append(keyDict[letter])

    for num in textValue:
        finalValue.append((num-keyValue[counter%len(keyValue)])%43)
        counter+=1


    for num in finalValue:
        finalString+=refDict[num]

    return finalString


##################################
#This is the user interface.
##################################

choice=raw_input('Would you like to: 1)Encrypt or 2)Decrypt?  Pick 1 or 2: ')

if choice=='1':
    textType=raw_input("Would you like to: 1)encrypt a text file or 2) input the text to be encrypted? Pick 1 or 2: ")

    if textType=='1':
        cryptName=raw_input( 'Please enter the name of the text file you would like to encrypt(eg. text.txt): ')
        newName=raw_input('Please name the file in which the encrypted text will be stored(eg. secret.txt):' )
        cipher=raw_input("Now enter your personal encryption key(eg. secret code):" )

        cryptFile=open(cryptName, 'r')
        newFile=open(newName, 'w')
        print >> newFile, Crypt(cryptFile.read(),cipher)
        cryptFile.close()
        newFile.close()
        print "Ok, all done!"
    elif textType=='2':
        inputText=raw_input('Ok, please input the text you would like to encrypt(eg. computers rock!): ')
        cipher=raw_input("Now enter your personal encryption key (eg. ultra secret code): ")
        if inputText=='': print 'Oops, no text was entered! Try again!'
        else:
            print Crypt(inputText, cipher)
    else:
        print 'Try again!'

elif choice=='2':
    textType=raw_input("Would you like to:1)decrypt a text file or 2) input the text to be decrypted? Pick 1 or 2: ")
    if textType=='1':
        decryptName=raw_input( 'Please enter the name of the text file you would like to decrypt(eg. text.txt): ')
        newName2=raw_input('Please name the file in which the decrypted text will be stored(eg. secret.txt):' )
        cipher=raw_input("Now enter the encryption key that was used to encrypt the file(eg. secret code):" )
        #Text decrypt
        decryptFile=open(decryptName, 'r')
        newFile2=open(newName2, 'w')
        print>> newFile2, Decrypt(decryptFile.read(),cipher)
        #other stuff
        #textTodecrypt=decryptFile.read()
        #newFile2.writelines(Decrypt(textTodecrypt, cipher))


        decryptFile.close()
        newFile2.close()
        print "Ok, all done!"

    elif textType=='2':
        inputText=raw_input('Ok, please input the text you would like to decrypt(eg. dig&ak:do): ')
        cipher=raw_input("Now enter the encryption key that was used to encrypt the text (eg. ultra secret code): ")
        if inputText=='': print 'Oops, no text was entered! Try again!'
        else:
            print Decrypt(inputText, cipher)

print "Have a nice day!"


#there is an issue with the newline character
```

Comment: The formatting for this question makes it incredibly difficult to help. Can someone (or yourself) please try to make it a tad bit more readable?

Comment: Why are you making up your own "encryption" scheme? Aren't there enough real ones available?

Comment: I will try to fix the formatting in a minute. sorry.

Comment: \n IS one character.  What are you asking?

Answer (score 10):

'\n' is one character. It is a new line escape character and is just a representation of the new line.

please rephrase your question in a readable way.

[Edit]
I think I know what your problem is. I ran your program and it is working just fine. You are probably trying to pass '\n' to your program from the command line. That will not work!

You see, if you gave raw_input() this string: `line1\nline2` it will escape the `\n` and make it `\\n` like this: `'line1\\nline2'`

So a quick hacky fix is to find and replace '\\n' with '\n':

```
text.replace('\\n', '\n')
```

I don't like this. But it will work for you.

A much better way is to read multiple lines, like this:

```
input = raw_input('Please type in something: ')
lines = [input]
while input:
    input = raw_input()
    lines.append(input)

text = '\n'.join(lines)

print text
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed? e.g. on Windows, when you write '\n' to a file? I ask that because IIRC Mircosoft's C runtime automatically converts '\n' to '\r\n'.

Comment: im not sure what you mean. If i run the Crypt funtion on a bunch of text, with new lines, and then decrypt it; it works fine. If i try to do that with text files, it gets all mixed up. If that makes sense.

Comment: For clarity's sake (because people often get confused):  

text = text.replace('\\n', '\n')

Comment: There may be other reasons to pass '\n' from the shell. For example if you want to specify some split-character or join character to be used.
In that case it's better to use `str.decode("string-escape")` than a `str.replace`[as I wrote in my answer].

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that your real problem is not with reading in \n as a '\' 'n' -- internally, Python should automagically translate \n into a single character.

My guess is that the real problem is that your newlines are probably actually two characters -- carriage return ('\r') and newline ('\n').  Try handling \r in addition to \n, and I wonder if that won't make your problem go away.

Comment: Ok, i will give this a try right now. Sorry for the horrible formatting.

Comment: From running the script, it seems the problem is raw_input() treats \n as a literal \ and a literal n, and there is no mapping for \ in keyDict..

Comment: Great point, DBR -- I didn't run his script, but you did.  I voted up your answer -- I think you've got the most likely response.

Answer (score 4):

I assume the problem is if there is \n in the text to be decrypted, it breaks:

```
KeyError: \

module body   in untitled at line 166
function Crypt    in untitled at line 94
```

Basically, `raw_input()` returns a string containing two characters `\` and `n` - and you have no mapping for `\` thus the error.

The simplest solution is so simply replace the literal characters `\n` with the `\n` escape sequence

```
def Crypt(text, cipher):
    text.replace(r"\n", "\n")
    ...
```

The raw string `r"\n"` creates a string containing the literal character `\` followed by `n` (the same as doing `"\\n"`).

In a regular string `"\n"` it's treated as the escape-sequence for a new-line. So the above code-block replaces `\n` in text with an newline.

You may have to define a mapping for "\n" in your `keyDict` mapping.

Another solution would be to split the text using `text.split(r"\n")` and treat each line separately. Or as others have suggested, use [`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord) every character and deal with numbers, rather than making your own numerical mapping.

> `ord(c)`
>   Given a string of length one, return an integer representing the Unicode code point of the character when the argument is a unicode object, or the value of the byte when the argument is an 8-bit string. For example, `ord('a')` returns the integer 97, `ord(u'\u2020')` returns 8224. This is the inverse of `chr()` for 8-bit strings and of `unichr()` for unicode objects.

As the docs explains, [`chr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr) is the opposite, and will turn the number back into a ASCII or Unicode character:

> `chr(i)`
>   Return a string of one character whose ASCII code is the integer i. For example, `chr(97)` returns the string 'a'. This is the inverse of `ord()`. The argument must be in the range [0..255], inclusive; ValueError will be raised if i is outside that range.

Basically you would do..

```
def Crypt(text, cipher):
    keyvalue = [ord(x) for x in cipher)
    textvalue = [ord(x) for x in text]
```

..instead of the two for loops (the [list-comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is basically the same as making a list, looping over each character in text or cipher, and appending to the list each time)

Comment: This sounds like it's the most likely answer.  Well done, DBR.

Answer (score 3):

Newline character is a single character.

```
>>> a = '\n'
>>> print len(a)
1
>>> a = '\n\n\n'
>>> a[1]
'\n'
>>> len(a)
3
>>> len(a[0])
1
```

So you misunderstand what your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to Python, but there could be a way to simplify what you are doing by using the **ord** and **chr** functions to change characters to ASCII values and vice versa. Here's a link to the [built-in function documentation in Python](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should probably take advantage of a number's numeric value to perform your encryption and avoid those big data structures that will fail for non-ascii text anyway.

Comment: His encryption is merely a very simple character shuffle/replacement.  I doubt binary encryption is a concern.

Comment: right. I am more just trying to create my own method. I realize it is not very complex, as compared to binary and hex etc.

Comment: It's a useful task while learning elementary programming, in any case. It forces you to learn about arrays, types, functional decomposition, input, output, and even streaming, depending on how you go about it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and fast way to replace the usual escapes with the corresponding ASCII characters is using the `str.decode` method:

```
>>> s = r'This string has\tsome\nescapes'
>>> s
'This string has\\tsome\\nescapes'
>>> s.decode('string-escape')
'This string has\tsome\nescapes'
>>> print s
This string has\tsome\nescapes
>>> print s.decode('string-escape')
This string has some
escapes
```